# Two @ModelAtributes from same Class different Objects in one form Spring FreeMarker

Tags: java, spring-boot, freemarker

I try to send a request to two different objects from one class from same form in freemarker if In this example is not working how can I set different values for each object since when i try with simple variables names it write it only in one of the objects.

**Controller**

```
@PostMapping(value = "/emergency_contacts")
public String setContacts(@ModelAttribute("emergency") EmergencyContact emergencyContact, @ModelAttribute("emergencyTwo") EmergencyContact emergencyContactTwo) {

    emergencyContactService.save(emergencyContact);
    emergencyContactService.save(emergencyContactTwo);

    return "redirect:/profile";
}
```

**HTML**

```
<form method="post" action="profile/emergency_contacts">
<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="form-group">
<input type="hidden" name="emergency.type" value="Primary">
    <label>Name <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
    <input name="emergency.name" type="text" class="form-control">
</div>
```

```
<div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
        <input type="hidden" name="emergency.type" value="Primary">
            <label>Name <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
            <input name="emergencyTwo.name" type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>

<button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Write a wrapper object that contains both objects or create a dedicated form object and do the conversion inside your controller method.

Comment: Yes this is a variant with the object wrapper, but I have 4 Classes if I need to do for each wrapper will be a lot of effort. I quiet don't catch what is a dedicated form object.I make it done try split method.